# asp.net core session creation with windows authentication

Tags: session, authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I am using windows authentication for an intranet asp.net core web application running behind IIS.
I'd like to log the event when a user accesses the application and a session is created.

Some of the authentication services provide a way to add an event-handler for events such as "OnSigningIn", "OnSignedIn", "OnTokenvalidated", etc., to options when configuring those services.

Is there a way to do something like that when using Windows Authentication through services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) or services.AddSession(), or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows authentication happens at the IIS level, before ASP.NET Core even sees the request, which is why there aren't any events for it you can handle. Sessions don't have any events either.

You could inject a simple middleware once you inject the logger into Startup,

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(ILogger<Startup> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // The typical startup crud, then

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            int logged = context.Session.GetInt32("Logged") ?? 0;
            if (visits == 0 && CheckIfThisRequestNeedsToUseSession(context))
            {
                // New session
                // Log with _logger, then mark so it doesn't repeat
                context.Session.SetInt32("IKnowYou", 1);
                // ...
            }
            await next();
        });
        // …
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok.  That's kind of what I'm working with now - looking at the User and Session data on each request to determine if this is the first request for a session or if the session's already been seen in the pipeline.  I was thinking there might be something more straightforward, but this will work.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: My requirement for an intranet app is similar in that I need to check if a session is new but not to log. The user network ID would be used to query a data table to get employee info not included in our AD account data. Am I correct that the code starting at "app.Use" would be the point where I could do that? Thanks.